# Angular JiT-compiling lazy-loaded module when using AoT

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I compiled my application using AoT and I have most of my modules lazy-loaded but I still see `JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents` method is taking ~1.5 seconds and going through all my modules (that shouldn't be loaded at this time)

I couldn't find any reference for such issue and was hoping someone here could explain this.

I can't produce a snippet, all I can supply is JavaScript profiler result:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what must be the time as per your expectation? How are you evaluating your expected time?

Comment: Try to use timeline to see what it actually compiles. How many components do you have?

Comment: CompileTemplate takes about 800ms. But I think the main issue here is that this method scans all of my modules (~12 modules)